# Use the devenv command to run a specific version of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

We have both Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 installed on our machine. Often we want to run it with the `devenv` command. To be clear, we want to open Visual Studio. How do we pass the version number to run? The [devenv command line documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx) doesn't say how.

Comment: Why don't you include to the path the appropriate devenv.exe? They are separate versions....

Comment: You run the copy of `devenv` that is in the folder for the version you want to launch. There's no command line parameter for devenv to select a version; it starts the version of VS that is in the folder it's in. That's why it's not in the docs - it doesn't exist.

Comment: @MikeCheel The problem is that I have two version. I would live to be able to run `devenv12` and `devenv10` for 2012 and 2010 respectively.

Comment: You are going to have to include the path the devenv.exe if you want a specific version. I don't think there is any way around it.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/892008/in-the-run-dialog-differentiate-between-two-identically-named-executables